# How is the 'impact' number derived in our profiles?

Tags: support

When I look in my MVM&A profile it shows I have reached approximately 7000 users.  When I look at my meta MVM&A profile it indicates I have reached 126,000 users.  How is this number derived and why is my meta so much larger than my standard profile on the site?

Comment: I would just like to comment that what I've reached on the main site (as of this post) is 1.9m now ... what I've reached on Meta ... ***1K*** ... I guess I'm disappointing in some areas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a [post on the StackExchange blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/) that talked about the impact calculation.

I also found a slightly updated overview in a meta discussion over [here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)

I have to admit that seeing my impact measured in millions of people is both cool and terrifying. :-)

Comment: And I thought my measly 600k was something ... sheesh! Yes, cool and terrifying, lol '-)

Comment: Yeah, it's a strange thing for sure.

Comment: Say, do you have an updated link for this?  The post you linked to is no longer there...

Comment: @anonymous2 maybe?  Check the new link.